# How do I set splash screen and other activities in order at android manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to add my splash screen to appear first and then it will go to sign up page. My android manifest code is below. I know right now my intent default is on sign up and view is on splash. I tried my changing them in between. In that case, splash screen appears first and goes directly to mainactivity. Please help!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mohsin.tourlog">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".signin" />
        <activity android:name=".signup"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this(like this you have to implement yours):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="abhiandroid.com.splashscreen">

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/abhiandroid"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".signin"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

splash activity:

```
    public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

Handler handler;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashfile);

    handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },3000);

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. It helped.

Comment: Starting in Android 12 (API 31+), the application's Launch Screen is provided by the system and the application should not create its own, otherwise the user will see two splashscreens

Answer (score 0):

Remove your intent-filter from your "signup" activity.

from

```
 <activity android:name=".signup"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name=".signup"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" />
```

If you want to display your Splash Activity for a few seconds then proceed to your Signup. You'd likely want to use Handler class to wait for a few secs then call upon the activity using intent.

Answer (score 0):

First, `AndroidManifest` is to define activity for the system.
You should set

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

for your splash screen and in the splash screen set `startActivity()` whatever you want and whatever your condition.